# Real life example to reset the autoincrement value in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

Want to know the scenario where we need to reset the autoincrement value in database. If possible (Real life example I'm looking for).

Comment: Only real valid reason is to “reset” all tables in “starting position” when developing and testing. You should not change it while in production because wrong relations might come to exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no scenario where you **need** this. There are zero valid scenarios for that in this universe.

People will try to come up with a reason, but that reason won't be valid.

`auto_increment`:

- is a unique identifier
- is synthetic key. You must never rely on its value to figure out the record count or to sequentially enumerate invoices
- its **primary** job is to provide a unique identifier. InnoDB storage engine relies on it though, which is its secondary job - and something MySQL user is unaware of until they try to tamper with the `auto_increment` value.
- it's not meant to be sequential. It just uses **sequential algorithm** to obtain the next, unique value.

Therefore, the **need** to reset it doesn't exist. If you have the *need* to do so, you're using `auto_increment` wrong.

During development, you might want to truncate your tables to re-start the counter from 1, just to satisfy your own OCD. I do it too, but the reason isn't really valid and nothing happens if you leave it be.